# Makefile notdir funnction not working

Tags: bash, makefile

```
PROGRAMS =  programs/aes/aescrypt2      programs/aes/crypt_and_hash \
programs/hash/hello     programs/hash/generic_sum   \
programs/hash/md5sum        programs/hash/sha1sum       \
programs/hash/sha2sum       programs/pkey/dh_client     \
programs/pkey/dh_genprime   programs/pkey/dh_server     \
programs/pkey/gen_key                       \
programs/pkey/key_app       programs/pkey/key_app_writer    \
programs/pkey/mpi_demo      programs/pkey/pk_decrypt        \
programs/pkey/pk_encrypt        programs/pkey/pk_sign       \
programs/pkey/pk_verify     programs/pkey/rsa_genkey        \
programs/pkey/rsa_decrypt   programs/pkey/rsa_encrypt   \
programs/pkey/rsa_sign      programs/pkey/rsa_verify        \
programs/pkey/rsa_sign_pss  programs/pkey/rsa_verify_pss    \
programs/ssl/ssl_client1        programs/ssl/ssl_client2        \
programs/ssl/ssl_server     programs/ssl/ssl_server2        \
programs/ssl/ssl_fork_server    programs/ssl/mini_client        \
programs/ssl/ssl_mail_client    programs/random/gen_entropy \
programs/random/gen_random_havege               \
programs/random/gen_random_ctr_drbg             \
programs/test/ssl_cert_test programs/test/benchmark     \
programs/test/selftest      programs/test/ssl_test      \
programs/util/pem2der       programs/util/strerror      \
programs/x509/cert_app      programs/x509/crl_app       \
programs/x509/cert_req

.SILENT:
pod:
    for i in $(PROGRAMS);                   \
    do                                      \
        echo $(notdir $${i});                       \
    done;
```

I have posted a sample from one of my makefiles, in the above code the notdir function is not working as expected, can someone help me with what am I missing here ?

Comment: It is same for me, but if you put a string instead of variable, it works!

Comment: "notdir is processed before the static pattern rule is applied" but i don know how to fix it. I tried Eval method but no help!