# 'notdir' doesn't work in Makefile

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile like this:

```
OBJ_FILES := $(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/, $(patsubst %.cc, %.o, $(SRC_FILES)))
...
$(OBJ_FILES): %.o: src/$(notdir %.cc)
    $(CC) $< -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS)
```

`$(SRC_FILES)` is `a.cc`, while `$(OBJ_FILES)` is `obj/a.o`.

But when I run it I get the error info:

> make: *** No rule to make target src/obj/a.cc, needed by obj/a.o. 
>   Stop.

So my question is: why `$(notdir)` doesn't extract filename?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`notdir` is processed before the static pattern rule is applied, so the result of `$(notdir %.cc)` is literally `%.cc`, which is then substituted by the rule to give the path in your error message.

The following should work, there's a couple of shorthands you can use too, remember to set `CXX` rather `CC`.

```
OBJ_FILES := $(SRC_FILES:src/%.cc=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)

$(OBJ_FILES): $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: src/%.cc
    $(COMPILE.cc) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
```

Comment: Thanks! GNU make document `10.5.4 How Patterns Match` also talks about this question:)

Comment: also my notdir is not working. similiar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31238722/makefile-notdir-funnction-not-working . it is given to variable. So key sentence that "notdir is processed before the static pattern rule is applied" . i could not understand how to fix issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
OBJECTS = $(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/, $(patsubst %.cc,%.o, $(SRC_FILES)))
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.cc
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```